# How to send a token in all ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, token

Is there a way to send a token in all the ajax requests of a page, without writing it in every $.ajax({}) call?

Answer (score 0):

Use the global `beforeSend` AJAX event to modify any AJAX requests: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

update: I've just checked and it seems this events will be deprecated, so use this instead: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Answer (score 0):

You can set globally this
     var token = "some value";

```
     $.ajaxSetup
        (
           {
               cache:false,
               beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token); }
           }
        );
```

or you can set individually for a perticular request in beforesend option.

```
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token); }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set this at the begining of your script line:

```
    $(function () {
        var token = $('input[name="_csrf"]').val();
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            console.log("ajax token!!!");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
        });
    });
```

and then you normally can make all your ajax calls...

```
    $(function(){
        $('#ddlGiro').change(function(){
            var contentResult=document.getElementById('divComboComercio');
            var giro = $("#ddlGiro").val();
             $.ajax({
                 url: [[@{'/comun/comercios/obtener/'}]] + giro,
                 data:  {"origen" : 'AsignarLote'},
                 dataType:'text',
                 cache:false,
                 type:'POST',
                 success:function(response){
                     contentResult.innerHTML=response;
                 }                           
             });
        });
    });
```